# Could you please help me understand the Excel formula

Tags: excel

I am using the excel report that includes formulas was designed long back, since last few days i started facing issue with the formula in one the cells in the excel report.

The formula used is :

```
=SUM(('Defects Past SLA'!D4:D72="1 - High")*('Defects Past SLA'!P4:P72="Zero"))
```

`'here 'Defects Past SLA'` is sheet name
' In that sheet, column D has few cells with value `"1 - High"` and `P column` has few cells with value `"Zero".`

My only question is how `Sum function` is working here, could you please help me understand above formula. I tried a lot but could not make out what it meanse. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `SUM` actually counts all the rows where the column D of that sheet contains `1 - High` *and* where the column P of the same row contains `Zero`.

Here's an example with a smaller table:

```
A    B
1    0
0    1
0    0
1    1
```

If I do:

```
=SUM((A:A=1)*(B:B=1))
```

I will get the result of 1

`(A:A=1)` gives an array of TRUE and FALSE. When applied to the data above, we get:

```
A 
1  => True
0  => False
0  => False
1  => True
```

Substituting that in the formula, we get:

```
=SUM((True; False; False; True)*(B:B=1))
```

The same thing happens to column B:

```
B 
0  => False
1  => True
0  => False
1  => True
```

Substituting that in the formula, we get:

```
=SUM((True; False; False; True)*(False; True; False; True))
```

Now, True is the same as `1` in excel, whilst False is the same as `0`. This means, we can rewrite the above as:

```
=SUM((1; 0; 0; 1)*(0; 1; 0; 1))
```

This is a multiplication of arrays. First term of the array will be multiplied by the first term of the next array so that we have:

```
1 x 0 = 0
0 x 1 = 0
0 x 0 = 0
1 x 1 = 1
```

This means that if we substitute the results in the above formula, we get:

```
=SUM((0; 0; 0; 1))
```

And the sum of these values is 1.

---

Note that the equivalent formula for your given situation would be:

```
=COUNTIFS('Defects Past SLA'!D4:D72,"1 - High",'Defects Past SLA'!P4:P72,"Zero")
```

Comment: Thanks Jerry. COUNTIFS() function worked for me. But when I tried using SUM() function,  it is not working. Lets suppose I wanted to count the cells  having value 1 in a column A, then  =SUM(A:A=1) should output value '2' but it is showing '0'. Does 'SUM' function not accept Range, does it have to be only A:A and can't be A1:A12. Could you please help me understand more about SUM Function with respective to a range of values.

Comment: @Srekk When you invoke the SUM function in this way, you have to "array enter" it (since it is using arrays and is by nature, not an array function). To array enter it, hold Ctrl+Shift and then press Enter after typing in the formula.

Comment: Oh that is where i did mistake. Now it is very clear. Thank you for giving clear picutre.